# Vite build fails on netlify because of a import, but works locally

Tags: vue.js, vite, netlify

I have a problem that I have no build error locally and as soon as I deploy with Netlify using Git deploy I get the following error:

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/dist/css/app.pcss" from "src/main.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
```

My Folder structure is as-

```
.
├── README.md
├── dist
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── favicon
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── images
│   │   ├── index.e1359b3f.js
│   │   └── index.fb503937.css
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── app.pcss
│   │   └── base
│   │       ├── fonts.pcss
│   │       ├── global.pcss
│   │       ├── headings.pcss
│   │       └── modern-css-reset.pcss
│   └── index.html
├── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.cjs
├── public
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── favicon
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   └── images
│   └── css
│       ├── app.pcss
│       └── base
│           ├── fonts.pcss
│           ├── global.pcss
│           ├── headings.pcss
│           └── modern-css-reset.pcss
├── src
│   ├── App.vue
│   ├── _components
│   ├── _pages
│   ├── main.js
│   └── router
├── tailwind.config.cjs
└── vite.config.js
```

And I'm importing `/dist/css/app.pcss` in `src/main.js` like that:

```
import '/dist/css/app.pcss'
```

I will be grateful if you have any ideas:)

The goal is a successful build on **netlify** via **git deplo**y and thus a successful import of the `app.pcss` file after the build.

Comment: You should not import it from `dist`, seems strange to me. That one is a built folder, use a "regular one" instead. Like one located in `src` for example. For some reason, you have all of your assets and CSS in `public`, while those should be more suited nested inside of `src`.

Comment: Ouu thanks, I had a thinking error. Works now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than importing from `dist`, OP moved his style files towards `/src/css` and it's now working successfully on Netlify.

Indeed, `dist` is mainly used as a target for a production app and never as an asset source.
While `public`, is more for hosting a light resource (like a `.pdf`) or alike, something that a visitor may need to download at some point on his computer.